# JQuery doesn't work inside 'this' div

Tags: vue.js

I have the problem with `<nowyboardal>`.

If 2 inputs are inside `<nowyboardal>`, then showing `disable` doesn't work. If they aren't inside - everything works. How I can fix this code to make my JQuery work?

```
<form method='POST' id='form_delete_account'>
<main v-cloak class='styl-1'>
  <p data-toggle='modal' class='styl-2' @click='toggleModal()'>{$lang['s_009']}</p>
  <nowyboardal id='showpopup' v-if='modal.isOpen' :has-mask='modal.hasMask' :can-click-mask='modal.canClickMask' :has-x='modal.hasX' @toggle='toggleModal'>
    <nowyarticle v-cloak>
      <nowysection>$user_style_account_delete</nowysection>
      <nowysection>
        <h3 class='d_tr'>{$lang['s_057']}</h3>
          <fieldset class='material d_ct'>
            <div style='text-align:left'>
              <input required type='new-password' name='password' id='i_delete_account'>
              <label>{$lang['s_051']}</label>
              <hr>
            </div>
          </fieldset>
          <div class='d-e-b-c'>
            <input class='delete-account-button' type='submit' id='b_delete_account' value='{$lang['s_059']}' disabled='true'/>
          </div>
        </form>
      </nowysection>
    </nowyarticle>
  </nowyboardal>
</main>
```

JS

```
$('#i_delete_account').keyup(function(){
  var i_delete_account = $('#i_delete_account').val();
  if (i_delete_account.length > 5) {
    $('#b_delete_account').prop('disabled', false);
  } else {
    $('#b_delete_account').prop('disabled', true);
  }
});
```

Comment: You've tagged this as jQuery but your HTML contains a number of Vue.js constructs.  If you're using Vue you should *not* be making state changes via jQuery, because the framework won't know you've done it and will overwrite your changes.  Handle this data manipulation in a Vue component method.

Comment: It looks like you are using jQuery and Vue. Why don't you use only Vue?

Comment: @DanielBeck How this `JS` will look using Vue?

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a free coding service. Please review the Vue.js documentation--it's incredibly short and pretty easy to follow--and return later after you've attempted to solve the problem yourself if you run into any difficulties. We can help you more then. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/

Comment: @AdamNickens  You could set your event handlers using `v-on:keyup`, get the password value into the component state using `v-model`, and manage the `disabled` attribute with another component state variable  (`:disabled="yourVariableName"`) instead of setting it on the DOM directly.  This should be very straightforward to write if you're already using Vue for other tasks.